# HTML how to get canvas resource file?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, resources, imagesource

The picture on the HTML page is represented as a canvas, but I have problems getting the source image name of this canvas, using javascript.

[image]

Page: https://www.futbin.com/22/squad-builder

I found this image in the page resources:
[image]

But how to get it programmically? I mean, if i have:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('field-area')
```

How to get the file name? Result should be "field_1920x1080.png?v=8"

Comment: You got the file name already, it's "filed_1920..." Or do tou want to get it programmatically? Why? And what kind of scripts can you run (since this is clearly not for a website you own)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to get the image drawn on the canvas `base64 encoded`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('field-area');
var b64url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

This will return the url for the image itself, i don't think you can get the Asset name directly from a `canvas` element without inspecting the code on the website

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer) But I hope that there still is such an opportunity to get the Asset name of the file.

Comment: i don't think you can get them as far as i remember but yeah good luck

Answer (score 0):

EJBEAN is right, the canvas element doesn't know what resources were used to draw.

Why don't you use `dataset` to keep an eye on what you used?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('field-area');
// ... draw resource here
canvas.dataset.resource = "field_1920x1080.png";
```

It's an easy way to keep data stored for any element on your page.

Comment: Yea this is a viable answer too, ^^